# Android studio: An error has occured

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on programming a android application. But as soon as I would like to test my application in my simulator, I get an instant error.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button toPech = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toPech);
    toPech.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton toInfo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.toInfo);
    toInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    //this button is not in the same layoutactivity as the other 2.
    ImageButton backPech = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.backPech);
    backPech.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toPech:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.toInfo:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.backPech:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

I would like to know what is wrong so that I can.

Comment: can you give logcat?

Answer (score 0):

From your commented line:

> //this button is not in the same layoutactivity as the other 2.

I think you have a **NullPointerException**.

While the `Button` *"backPech"* isn't in `activity_main.xml`, so calling `findViewById(R.id.backPech);` will return a `null` object ( `backPech` will be null).

And calling `setOnClickListener(this);` to a `null` object will cause the NullPointerException.

Comment: Ah thanks. but can u give me an example of the solution?

Comment: Just declare a Button with id = "backPech" in your *activity_main.xml* ( like you did in the other activity xml)